# Mousedown/Mouseup Event overriding Mouseenter/Mouseleave Event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button where it's background changes when you hover, as well as when you click it. To make it so it changes when you click, I made it to where you use the `mousedown` event. This seems to override the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. When the `mousedown` event happens, it seems to disable the CSS hover events. I have already tried to add mouseenter and mouseleave, and it hasn't worked.

```js
            let button = document.querySelector(".shoot");

            button.addEventListener("mousedown",()=>{
                // REMEMBER TO FIX HOVER EFFECTS
                button.style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";           
            })

            
            button.addEventListener("mouseup",()=>{
                button.style.backgroundColor = "#d3d3d3";
            })
```

```css
.shoot {
    width:200px;
    padding-top:20px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:18px;
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    border-radius:30px;
    font-family:Semi-Casual;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}
.shoot:hover {
    background-color:#c3c3c3;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="shoot">
    Shoot
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline styles will take precedence over the CSS rules defined in a stylesheet, so that's why the hover effect is not working as expected.

So, instead of using Javascript to set the backgroundColor directly, use javascript to [add a css class to the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), which ultimately uses CSS (also) to set the background-color.

```js
let button = document.querySelector(".shoot");

button.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    button.classList.add("active");
});

button.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    button.classList.remove("active");
});

button.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    button.classList.remove("active"); // this ensures the button returns to its normal state even if the mouse is still down
});
```

```css
.shoot {
    width:200px;
    padding-top:20px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:18px;
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    border-radius:30px;
    font-family:Semi-Casual;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}

.shoot:hover {
    background-color:#c3c3c3;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.shoot.active {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="shoot">
    Shoot
</div>
```

Comment: I apologize, but could you clarify what you mean by using javascript to add a css class? Thanks.

Comment: In the code I provided, you can see that we're using javascript to add or remove the css `.active` class to the the html element so that the appropriate css class controls the style of the element during mousedown, mouseup, and mouseleave events. Before, you were styling the html element directly on its style attribute (instead of a css class), and the CSS cannot override that direct styling without an [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important) flag (which I try to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

Use event `mouseover` / `mouseout`. Also don't force `mouseup` on the element as it won't do what you want because if i drag the mouse out the thing is still there